# How to wrap a resource which depends on async call

Tags: angularjs

I have a service which wraps a resource. I have had to refactor it to take a param (websiteId) which is gotten from an async call. I thought I could just wrap the resource inside the resource, but I am getting a standard injection error.

What is the correct way to have a service which wraps a resource, use a param which comes from a promise?

```
searchApp.factory('MyTestService', ['$resource', 'WebsiteService', 'appConfig',  function ($resource, WebsiteService, appConfig) {
  WebsiteService.getCurrentWebsiteId().then(function(websiteId){
     return $resource(appConfig.apiBaseUrl + 'tests/:id/?website=:websiteId', {
        websiteId: websiteId
    });
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try this approach:

```
searchApp.factory( 'MyTestService', [ '$resource', 'WebsiteService', 'appConfig', '$q'  function ( $resource, WebsiteService, appConfig, $q ) {
  var getService = function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    WebsiteService.getCurrentWebsiteId( function( websiteId ) {
      defer.resolve({ 
        websiteId : websiteId, 
        resource : $resource( appConfig.apiBaseUrl + 'tests/:id/?website=:websiteId', {
          websiteId: '@websiteId'
        })
      });
    });
    return defer.promise;
  };
  return getService;
}]);
```

Main differences are:

- Returning a promise from your service.
- Parameter value prefixed with an @ -> then the value for that
  parameter will be extracted from the corresponding property on the
  data object (provided when calling an action method). For example, if
  the defaultParam object is {someParam: '@someProp'} then the value of
  someParam will be data.someProp.

### EDIT

**How to use it**

Since this service is returning a promise which value is a resource object, to use it you first have to resolve the service promise and then call the appropiate resource class object (Im using the same terminology than Angular documentation). Once you have your resource class object, you can request your resource and resolve it.

The correct usage will be:

```
MyTestService.then( function( responseObject ) {
  responseObject.resource.get( { websiteId : responseObject.websiteId }, function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
  })
});
```

Another different history is why will you need this.
If I were you, I will create different resources and then just nest promises, in order to resolve one before getting the other.

But thats was not your question.

Comment: Interesting approach, but when I call MyTestService.getService() I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: MyTestService.getService is not a function.

Comment: Ok, I edit my answer plus I updated also the service. Forgot to deal with  websiteId on the first request. As I commented on the edit, is a weird use case and I think you will accomplish better results by not doing on this way. But again, that was not your question.